# Google Play Services - Could not find dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Androidにて開発を行っておりますが
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1`
上記のgradleにlocationを入れようとするとエラーになってしまいます。
古いバージョンの11.0.2は問題なく入るのですが、そうするとそれ以外の依存しているライブラリーが古いと言われビルドエラーになってしまうため、最新を入れる必要があります。
解決策を探していますが以下のようなことはすべて試しました。

- build.gradleにgoogle()を入れる
- google Play Serviceを入れる
- Support Repositoryを入れる

エラーの内容としては、

ビルド時には以下の内容

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

一番上のInstallを行うと途中で止まってしまい以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
```

build.gradleの中身を貼り付けますので何が問題か回答いただければ幸いです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: build.gradleの中身は画像ではなくテキストで張り付けていただいた方が見やすく、再現しようとする方に親切です。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/146207

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました！
buildscript側のみgoogle()が記述されていたためでした
android内にgoogle()を追加したところ取得できるようになりました。